# How is system-as-root mounted in Android 9?

Tags: mount, system, partitions, ab-partition

In Android 9, `system.img` consist of system and ramdisk. So kernel will mount `system.img` directly and implement `init` program. Next, `init` will parse `init.rc` file and mount remaining partitions based on `fstab` file. But, there is some thing in `fstab` file that I don't understand :

```
/dev/block/by-name/system      /      ext4    ro,barrier=1
```

Here, system is mounted as root in `fstab` file. I thought that `system.img` is mount before to execute `init` program but here, `system.img` is mouted again. Can someone explain this for me?

Answer (score 0):

> `init` will parse `init.rc` file and mount remaining partitions based on `fstab` file.

Not all partitions in `fstab` are mounted by `init` on boot. [Exemptions](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r50/fs_mgr/fs_mgr.cpp#817) include partitions managed by `vold` and those only meant for recovery mode, raw partitions (not mountable) and root partition.

> There is some thing in `fstab` file that I don't understand :
>
> ```
> /dev/block/by-name/system      /      ext4    ro,barrier=1
> ```

That `fstab` entry is incomplete because it doesn't include `fs_mgr` flags as per [standard format](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r50/fs_mgr/fs_mgr_priv.h#50). Complete entry should be like:

```
/dev/block/by-name/system    /    ext4    ro,barrier=1    wait,recoveryonly
```

On Treble devices (Android 8 and 9) *“devices can specify [fstab entries](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/kernel/mounting-partitions-early#fstab-entries) for early mounted partitions using device tree overlays”*. An simple explanation can be found [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/LineageOS/comments/9yli9q). However *“In Android 10 and higher, devices must specify `fstab` entries for early mounted partitions using an `fstab` file”* and *“must place the `fstab` file in the `ramdisk` and in the `vendor` partition”*.

DTB is usually appended as blob to kernel binary and `fstab` entries are exposed in `procfs`:

```
~# cat /proc/device-tree/firmware/android/fstab/*/name
system
vendor
```

So on devices where `fstab` entries for partitions `system`, `vendor` and `odm` are in Device Tree Blob, `init` takes no action for these partitions on `mount_all` because `fs_mgr` flags include [`recoveryonly`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r50/fs_mgr/fs_mgr_fstab.cpp#91). You can comment out or remove the entry and the device should boot normally.